# This expression was expected to have type list<char> but here has type 'a list

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

The function `numbersDictionary` tries to make an associative array,and the `takeVal` tries to get the value of a corresponding key.

```
let numbersDictionary =
 let d = [('I', 1); ('V', 5); ('X', 10); ('L', 50); ('C', 100); ('D', 500); ('M', 1000)] |> Map.ofList
 d

let takeVal par = 
    match par with
        | Some(v) ->  v
        | None -> 0 


let rec evaluate( numbersInchar:List<char>)=
    match numbersInchar with
    |[] -> []
    |head::tail -> takeVal (numbersDictionary.TryFind head)::evaluate tail
```

at the first line of matching  `|[] -> []`, i faced with the following erorr:

```
This expression was expected to have type  list<char> but here has type 'a list
```

Neither I cannot explain this problem nor solve it.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you post complete code snippet? Without that, it is impossible to see what's going on...

Comment: As is the code compile fine and evaluate has signature : `char list -> int list`.

Comment: Yes, the code is fine. Maybe you need reset your REPL window

Comment: F# Interactive > Reset

Comment: Doesn't work, still complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let numbersDictionary =
    [('I', 1); ('V', 5); ('X', 10); ('L', 50); ('C', 100); ('D', 500); ('M', 1000)] 
    |> Map.ofList

let takeVal = function
    | Some v -> v
    | None   -> 0 

let rec evaluate = function
    | [] -> []
    | head::tail -> takeVal (numbersDictionary.TryFind head)::evaluate tail

evaluate ['X'; 'V']
// val it : int list = [10; 5]
```